# Not able to see S3 bucket images from newly added ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

My application is running on AWS with some ec2 instances having single abc.ppk key. The Product images are on S3 buckets and it have public permission.

Now I have added another ec2 instance with pqr.ppk key. However, after adding this instance sometimes we are not able to see the product images.
Its clear that My newly added instance is not fetching images from S3 bucket.

What I have to do so that my newly added instance (with different .ppk file) shows the product images?

What am I missing? Do I need to add newly added instance details to S3 bucket or S3 bucket details in newly added instance?
If yes, What to add and where to add?

your help is highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What is exactly the permissions on your S3 files? If it's public, then anyone with the URL should be able to download it, who has internet Access. There is no PPK files needed.
If you want restrict access for S3 objects from EC2 instances, then use IAM roles, much easier and Security best practice.
Also are you trying to list the objects on S3? That's a different permission.